# NodeJS MySQL, reconnecting on connection loss?

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

```
function Connect() {
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : 'hidden',
        user     : 'hidden',
        password : 'hidden',
        database : 'hidden'
    });

    connection.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error connecting to Database'.red);
            setInterval(Connect, 5000);
            connection.end();
            }else{
            console.log('Connected to Database'.green);
        }

    });
}

Connect();
```

I am attempting to make it so my code won't crash if the database loses connection.

It will be connected to a database which is prone to many restarts and updates, meaning that the program will crash upon losing connection.

I tried adding  `setInterval(Connect, 5000);` so it would attempt to reconnect if it loses connection but to no luck.

Can someone help me out where I am going wrong?

Comment: Consider using [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org) if you're just getting started with Node and databases.

Comment: @tadman beat me to it. Sequelize is a phenomenal tool for Node JS and DB connections. I would also raise the question of why would it continue to connect and then lose connection? Seems like an arch problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the `mysql` npm package you can use connection pooling provided by the library:

https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections

> When a previous connection is retrieved from the pool, a ping packet is sent to the server to check if the connection is still good.

It's rather easy to use, instead of using `createConnection` you can use `createPool`

```js
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 2,
  host            : 'example.org',
  user            : 'bob',
  password        : 'secret',
  database        : 'my_db'
});
```

And then use the pool to query the database.

It has many additional benefits as well e.g. load balancing connections.

Comment: After doing what you said I have the exact same issue :(

Comment: It turns out that the pool already does these checks automatically meaning there is no problem and I didn't need to add the function setinterval